# How to graph the group during the last 7 days of the last year

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to graph the reported infections of the countries that belong to the group during the last 7 days of the last year

```
a= subset(datac, datac$'location'=="") 
datac_update<-as.Date(a$date) 
max(datac_update) 
b = subset(a,datac_update>max(datac_update-7))

g= subset(datac, datac$'location'=="") 
greenland_update<-as.Date(g$date) 
max(greenland_update) 
green = subset(g,greenland_update>max(greenland_update-7))

u= subset(datac, datac$'location'==" ") 
united_update<-as.Date(u$date) 
max(united_update) 
united = subset(u,united_update>max(united_update-7))

g3 <- ggplot()+ geom_line(datac =b,mapping = aes(x= date, y = new_cases), col="blue",size = 1) + geom_point(datac =b,mapping = aes(x= date, y = new_cases), col="black",alpha= 0.8)+ ggtitle("COVID-19 weekly cases in Canada") + xlab("Date") + ylab("COVID 19 Cases in Canada") 
g3

g4 <- ggplot()+ geom_line(datac =green,mapping = aes(x= date, y = new_cases), col="red",size = 1) + geom_point(datac =green,mapping = aes(x= date, y = new_cases), col="blue",alpha= 0.8)+ ggtitle("") + xlab("") + ylab("") 
g4
```

Comment: Hi Nguyen and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question makes the assumption that we know something about your data, what structure it has, what groups you are talking about, what year you are referring to, what your current plot looks like, and what error your current code gives. Unfortunately, you haven't included any of this in your question, so it's going to be hard to help you. Please edit your question to include some reproducible data. Thanks

Comment: Following up on Allan's comment, it will be extremely challenging to answer your question without at least a sample of your data. Please provide the output of `dput(datac)` or `dput(head(datac))` if your data is very large. Paste the output directly into your question by pressing the [edit] button. You can use three backticks (`) for better formatting.